# What is the gremlin query for sorting by putting empty values at the bottom

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am trying to find an equivalent for the below SQL query in the Gremlin query.

`select * from test.test_table order by alias = '', alias asc, name asc;`

The above query does the sorting based on ascending order by putting empty rows at the bottom.
[image]

In the Gremlin query, I am trying to write the below query but alias property with empty values are coming at the top.

I want to have proper sorting for the alias field but empty and null values should go at the bottom.

```
g.V("ID").inE('RELATIONSHIP_NAME').outV().order().by('alias', asc).by('name', asc).valueMap().toList()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found the correct answer which is working.

```
g.V("ID").
  inE('RELATIONSHIP').
  outV().
  order().
    by(choose(values('alias').is(''),constant(1), constant(0)), asc).
    by('alias', asc).by('name', asc).range(0,-1).valueMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this limitation by doing:

```
g.V("ID").inE('RELATIONSHIP_NAME').outV().
    order().
      by(values('alias').choose(within(['', null]), constant('zzz'), identity())).
      by('name').
    valueMap().toList()
```

A working example using the Modern TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g=graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name', '').property('age',33)
==>v[13]
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name', '').property('age',23)
==>v[16]
gremlin> g.V().order().by(values('name').choose(within(['', null]), constant('z'), identity())).by('age').values('name')
==>josh
==>lop
==>marko
==>peter
==>ripple
==>vadas
==>
==>
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting malformed query exception from gremlin console.

Comment: Added a working example that you can paste and copy for reference.